# create setup for VSTO Outlook in C # VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, ms-office

I created an addin for Outlook C # and now want to install on multiple machines, so I was looking for how to create a setup to run and install on any machine, so when you open Outlook addin appear immediately. 
This would addin for Outlook 2010 and 2013. Can anyone help me?

PS: I am not using the addin-express, only Microsoft tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the required steps are described in the following articles:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx)

Comment: If you have forms associated with addin need some more step in the installation?

Comment: Are you talking about customized Outlook item forms (e.g. "IPM.Contact.YourForm") or Windows Forms?

Comment: What forms are you talking about? Is it an Outlook form region or just a regular Windows form?

Comment: Windows Form. For example, when you click the button (which is on the Ribbon) opens a form, this form is in the project, he also goes along with the dll or we need to do more?